# bootstrap-datepicker.как развернуть выбор даты?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть классический календарь бутстрап. Выбирает текущую дату по умолчанию и позволяет выбрать одну из следующих дат.Предыдущие даты задизэйблены. Надо сделать так, чтобы можно было выбирать предыдущие даты, но нельзя было бы выбирать последующие даты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  endDate: '+0d',
  autoclose: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-end-date="+0d">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. На весь экран.

Answer (score 1):

За отключение после сегодняшнего дня отвечает параметр [endDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate)

За начальную дату отвечает параметр [startDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

```
$ ( '.datepicker' ). datepicker ({ 
    format :  'mm / dd / yyyy' , 
    startDate :  '-3d',
    endDate : '0d'
});
```